# C# Entity Framework: Get the Parent of the Children after a Select

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to 'keep' the reference to the parent in the object after a query to EF starting by the parent entity while filtering on the both parent and children and returning the children.  But those children records i'm returning need to maintain their reference back to the parent.

In the example below, the parent is available 'up until the select' is performed, and then the children are returned... but the reference 'back' to the parent is lost.   HOW can i not loose that object of the parent???

so what i need is that the return result of Table2Model, still holds reference back to parent in the MODEL.. but after the select statement that reference is lost.

if i add this

```
result.ForEach((t2) =>
  {
    t2.Table1 = db.Table1Model.SingleOrDefault(t1 => t1.Table1Id == t2.Table1Id);
  });
```

it fixes my problem... but i was wondering if there was some way to retain the parent reference in the original call. Doing this in two steps doubles the work effort of the query.

(db below is the database context)

```
public class Table1Model {
    public Table1Id {get; set;}
    public Name {get; set;}
    public Desc {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Table2Model> Table2Models {get; set;}
}

public class Table2Model {
    public Table2ModelId {get; set;}
    public SpecialData1 {get; set;}
    public SpecialData2 {get; set;}
    public SpecialData3 {get; set;}
    public Table1Id {get; set;}
    public virtual Table1Model Table1 {get; set;}
}

public class List<Table2Model> DoWork(sampleRequest request){

    var result = db.Table1Model
        .Where(t => t.Name = request.Name)
        .Select(t => t.Table2Models.OrderByDescending(n => n.Table2ModelId).FirstOrDefault())
        .OrderBy(t2 => t2.SpecialData1)
        .Take(5)
        .ToList();

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Does your `Table2Model` table in the database have a `Table1Id` column on it? If you just reference that property, it should lazy-load the parent object. Alternatively, you could pull that parent once out of the database, and manually assign it to all of the children.

Comment: yes it does .. i just fixed it above

Comment: if i break down the query... the references load.. all points to each other... BUT as soon as the select query is run, and the table2models are projected... for some reason it looses the pointers to the parent.  (Table1 property of Table2Model is null)

Comment: Anything that projects the query (`Select`, `GroupBy`, etc) will cause "Includes" to be lost.  *Sometimes* you can  use `Include` after the projection, if you are projecting to a configured entity.

Comment: I see.. no way to retain it then? ... ah..ok ..let me try.. what Bradley mentioned.

Comment: Yes, ok. that did it.. i had tried the include after the project before, but i must have done something wrong.   Thx @BradleyUffner

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm missing something here, but why not project into a different model and include both pieces.

```
public class TheModel
{
    public Table1Model Table1Model { get; set; }
    public Table2Model Table2Model { get; set; }
}

var result = db.Table1Model
    .Where(t => t.Name = request.Name)
    .Select(t => new TheModel {
        Table1Model = t,
        Table2Model = t.Table2Models
            .OrderByDescending(n => n.Table2ModelId)
            .FirstOrDefault())
    .OrderBy(t2 => t2.Table2Model.SpecialData1)
    .Take(5)
    .ToList();
```

I'd actually suggest you break down `TheModel` into just the specific properties you need and be a little more granular with the request, but I don't know what exactly you need to can't give a more specific example.

Comment: I solved it using @BradleyUffner suggestion... i have tried it before, but must have had done something wrong.. now it works with an include 'after' the select projection.